# LINQ Group with nested list

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to group my data using LINQ. This is the model I use:

```
public class Employee
{
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
   public string LastName {get;set;}
   public IEnumerable<string> Groups {get;set;}
}
```

And I have the `IEnumerable<Employees>` and I want to transform this:

```
FirstName=TestName1, SecondName=TestName1, Groups { Group1, Group2 },
FirstName=TestName2, SecondName=TestName2, Groups { Group1, Group3 }
...
```

To this:

```
Key=Group1,
Values:
{
   FirstName=TestName1, SecondName=TestName1, Groups { Group1, Group2 };
   FirstName=TestName2, SecondName=TestName2, Groups { Group1, Group3 };
};
Key=Group2,
Values:
{
   FirstName=TestName1, SecondName=TestName1, Groups { Group1, Group2 };
};
...
```

So, I need to somehow revert grouping from 'grouping' `Groups` by `Employee`, to grouping `Employees` by `Group`. I've tried to use `GroupJoin` `Employees` with `Groups` (extracted them by `employee.SelectMany(e => e.Groups).Distinct();`), but my queries don't work. Could someone help me please?

Comment: Your example of groups make little sense to me. Why should two identical objects be placed in different groups?

Comment: Is this school task that you should resolve with linq and grouping ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `SelectMany` to expand the groups list before grouping:

```
List<Employee> employees = GetEmployees();
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Employee>> groupedEmployees = employees
    .SelectMany(employee => employee.Groups.Select(group => (employee, group)))
    .GroupBy(pair => pair.group, pair => pair.employee);
```

Comment: This solution works well, and your solution works too, Tim. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @TimSchmelter: [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ndIybr) - as you can see, the output is exactly what you would expect. No need to add another filter.

Answer (score 2):

You could alternatively identify the groups first and then create a dictionary.

```
var groups = employees
    .SelectMany(e => e.Groups)
    .Distinct();

var employeesByGroup = groups
    .ToDictionary(
        group => group,
        group => employees
            .Where(e => e.Groups.Contains(group)));
```

---

Note: As commented below, this will iterate over the source list multiple times, which may cause performance issues if `employees` is large.

Comment: Yeah, this is simple and works, i just would replace var with the dictionary type

Comment: This works well too, and it's quite simple. Thanks!

Comment: **NB:** This will iterate over the source list multiple times: once to get the list of groups, and once for each group to get the employees in that group. Depending on the size of the list and the number of groups, that could cause performance issues.